# Match only parts of a string in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a calculator in Java. I have a string argument that might look something like this:

```
23+48*26-4*sqrt26-exp.3-20%*25+56/33
```

I don't know how to create a RegEx that will match only nondecimal characters or strings. What I want the result to be is something like this:

```
String result = "+,*,-,*,sqrt,-,exp,-,%,*,+,/";
```

I'm using a string because I want to allow the user to modify the input before hitting the `=` sign.

Can somebody help me please? I'm really bad with RegEx.

Bellow is the function I use to calculate the result:

```
public double calculate(String operations) {
        String numberPattern = "[-+]?([0-9]*\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)";
        String operatorsPattern = "";
        Pattern number = Pattern.compile(numberPattern);
        Matcher matcher = number.matcher(operations);

        while(matcher.find()) {
            double num1 = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(1));
            String operator = operator(operations);

            // stergerea operatorului din string
            operations = operations.substring(operator.length()+1);

            if(!operator.equals("=")) {
                result = result(result, num1, operator);
            } else {
                return result;
            }

        }

        return result;
    }
```

And the operator function is something like this:

```
private String operator(String string) {
    String op = "";
    String toFind = "[\\D]";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(toFind);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

    op = matcher.group(1);

    return op;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: Looks like you need to implement an expression parser, plain regular expressions are not enogh, consider using [Reverse Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) or build [Syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) out of your expression

Comment: I have not understood how that will help you build a working calculator; but certainly regexp can do that.

Answer (score -1):

You first need to convert your expression in a Reverse Polish Notation:
5 + ((1 + 2) × 4) − 3 = 5 1 2 + 4 × + 3 −

For this task you can use [Shunting-yard algo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)

Then you can just use a [Post fix algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) to evaluate the expression

[Shunting-yard in Java](http://eddmann.com/posts/shunting-yard-implementation-in-java/)

[Post-fix algorithm in java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/43stack/Postfix.java.html) (It is just treats + *, but it is very simple to modify)